# Detecting the stock android browser with PHP?

Tags: php, android, compatibility, android-browser

As many of you might have encountered, the stock Android browser, thankfully discontinued in Android 4.4 is more or less the modern IE6 - riddled with bugs and broken to the point of inciting suicide amongst developers. Consequently, the need to serve resources specific to that browser is quickly becoming a necessity, and the best way to do that would be by linking stylesheets/js through the back end. So what's a fool proof way of detecting the browser using PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thankfully it's pretty simple:

```
//get the user agent string
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

//results array
$matches = [];

//perform regex query
preg_match ( '/Android.*AppleWebKit\/([\d.]+)/', $ua, $matches);

//Check if the regex query returned matches specific to 
//the android stock browser.
if( isset($matches[0]) && 

  //This is where we diffrentiate the stock browser from chrome, 
  //the default browser's webkit version never goes above 537
  ( isset($matches[1]) && intval($matches[1] < 537) ) ){
    echo 'Browsing via stock android browser';
}
```

Please add your improved answers.

Comment: Although it may not be completely bullet proof for some edge cases, from what I read in another SO thread, I think it will serve it's purpose fine when it comes to my own requirements. Which is the stock browser not being able to handle jQuery plugins using `$.extend`. Even adding a `try` block still breaks the script. So no choice but the sniff it out and conditionally paste different script links. Anyway, isn't the first `isset($matches[0])` a bit abundant? If the second one is in the array, the first one must also surely be. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php